# Pandas dataframe column value case insensitive replace where <condition>

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, case-insensitive

Is there a case insensitive version for pandas.DataFrame.replace? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

I need to replace string values in a column subject to a case-insensitive condition of the form "where label == a or label == b or label == c".

Comment: Can you add data sample and expected output?

Comment: Say column 1 has values ['test', 'Test', 'cat', 'CAT', 'dog', 'Cat'] and I want to replace all occurrences of 'test' and 'cat' with 'baby', irrespective of case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think need convert to [`lower`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) and then replace by condition with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
d = {'a':['test', 'Test', 'cat', 'CAT', 'dog', 'Cat']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

m = df['a'].str.lower().isin(['cat','test'])
df.loc[m, 'a'] = 'baby' 
print (df)
      a
0  baby
1  baby
2  baby
3  baby
4   dog
5  baby
```

Another solution:

```
df['b'] = df['a'].str.replace('test', 'baby', flags=re.I)
print (df)
      a     b
0  test  baby
1  Test  baby
2   cat   cat
3   CAT   CAT
4   dog   dog
5   Cat   Cat
```

Comment: I like the latter solution, but that doesn't support replacement of multiple strings in one shot. I have to run it multiple times, for 'test' and 'cat' separately. I'd like to do it in one shot.

Comment: I think it is not implemented in `Series.replace, DataFrame.replace`

Answer (score 22):

The issue with some of the other answers is that they don't work with all Dataframes, only with Series, or Dataframes that can be implicitly converted to a Series. I understand this is because the `.str` construct exists in the Series class, but not in the Dataframe class.

To work with Dataframes, you can make your regular expression case insensitive with the `(?i)` extension. I don't believe this is available in all flavors of RegEx but it works with Pandas.

```
d = {'a':['test', 'Test', 'cat'], 'b':['CAT', 'dog', 'Cat']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

    a       b
0   test    CAT
1   Test    dog
2   cat     Cat
```

Then use replace as you normally would but with the `(?i)` extension:

```
df.replace('(?i)cat', 'MONKEY', regex=True)

    a       b
0   test    MONKEY
1   Test    dog
2   MONKEY  MONKEY
```